# LoadRunner IP address binding to vuser

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

After last system update it require unique ip address authentication for each user. After some googling I find IP wizard and info about IP Spoffing. Right now LR offers a function, that set random ip address to vuser for each script run.
Here is a question:
How to set static ip address to vuser by its login to the system?
Like I have a pool that contains ip address and login and when vuser login to system it already have binded ip from pool.

Comment: You can either use parametrization or VTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the below functions you can get and set the IP address of the specific VUser. This could be done in *vuser_init()* or beginning of 1st action in script.

> *char* ***lr_get_vuser_ip( );**
>
> The `lr_get_vuser_ip` function returns the IPv4 address of a Vuser. When performing IP spoofing, each Vuser can use a different address. This function allows you to determine the current Vuser's IP address.
>
> If the IP was set with the `web_set_sockets_option` function using the *IP_ADDRESS_BY_INDEX* option, `lr_get_vuser_ip` returns that IP.
>
> To get an IPv6 address, use `lr_get_attrib_string("ipv6")`
>
> **Return Values**
>
> If this function succeeds , it returns a pointer to a string holding the IP address of the Vuser. If it fails, or if working with multiple IP addresses is disabled, it returns NULL.

and

> *int* **web_set_sockets_option( const char *option, const char *value );**
>
> **Return Values**
>
> This function returns *LR_PASS (0)* on success, and *LR_FAIL (1)* on failure.

**Example**

The `web_set_sockets()` function can be used like this:

```
 // Set current VUser IP address to 10.0.0.1
 web_set_sockets_option("USER_IP_ADDRESS", "10.0.0.1");
```